# Getting crash in WPF application in Tree View

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In our application we used WPF and have implemented a `TreeView`. This application works fine in all machines but in one machine (Windows 7, not all Windows 7 machines) it crashes.

When I rename a node in the `TreeView` and select other node it crashes.

Please provide me solution for this or is there any way we can find out why this issue occurs in a particular machine.

Note: This m/c is not a developer m/c.

## **Below is stack Trace:**

> Void OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.
>      at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   e)
>      at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   args)
>      at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateSubProperty(DependencyProperty
>   dp)
>      at
>   System.Windows.Freezable.GetChangeHandlersAndInvalidateSubProperties(EventStorage&
>   calledHandlers)
>      at
>   System.Windows.Freezable.GetChangeHandlersAndInvalidateSubProperties(EventStorage&
>   calledHandlers)
>      at
>   System.Windows.Freezable.GetChangeHandlersAndInvalidateSubProperties(EventStorage&
>   calledHandlers)
>      at
>   System.Windows.Freezable.GetChangeHandlersAndInvalidateSubProperties(EventStorage&
>   calledHandlers)
>      at System.Windows.Freezable.FireChanged()
>      at
>   System.Windows.Freezable.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   e)
>      at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   args)
>      at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex
>   entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata,
>   EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean
>   coerceWithDeferredReference, OperationType operationType)
>      at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(DependencyProperty
>   dp)
>      at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.Invalidate(Boolean
>   isASubPropertyChange)
>      at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TransferValue(Object
>   newValue, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
>      at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ScheduleTransfer(Boolean
>   isASubPropertyChange)
>      at MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.NewValueAvailable(Boolean
>   dependencySourcesChanged, Boolean initialValue, Boolean
>   isASubPropertyChange)
>      at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.UpdateSourceValueState(Int32
>   k, ICollectionView collectionView, Object newValue, Boolean
>   isASubPropertyChange)
>      at
>   MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.OnDependencyPropertyChanged(DependencyObject
>   d, DependencyProperty dp, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
>      at
>   MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.OnSourceInvalidation(DependencyObject
>   d, DependencyProperty dp, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
>      at
>   System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.HandlePropertyInvalidation(DependencyObject
>   d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
>      at
>   System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.OnPropertyInvalidation(DependencyObject
>   d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
>      at
>   System.Windows.DependentList.InvalidateDependents(DependencyObject
>   source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs sourceArgs)
>      at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   args)
>      at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex
>   entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata,
>   EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean
>   coerceWithDeferredReference, OperationType operationType)
>      at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp,
>   Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean
>   coerceWithDeferredReference, OperationType operationType, Boolean
>   isInternal)
>      at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyPropertyKey
>   key, Object value)
>      at System.Windows.Controls.TreeView.SetSelectedItem(Object data)
>      at System.Windows.Controls.TreeView.ChangeSelection(Object data,
>   TreeViewItem container, Boolean selected)
>      at System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem.Select(Boolean selected)
>      at
>   System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem.OnIsSelectedChanged(DependencyObject
>   d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
>      at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   e)
>      at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   e)
>      at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs
>   args)
>      at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex
>   entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata,
>   EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean
>   coerceWithDeferredReference, OperationType operationType)
>      at
>   System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp,
>   Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean
>   coerceWithDeferredReference, OperationType operationType, Boolean
>   isInternal)
>      at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp,
>   Object value)
>      at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp,
>   Boolean value)
>      at System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem.set_IsSelected(Boolean
>   value)
>      at
>   Lutron.Gulliver.QuantumResi.Common.StretchingTreeViewItem.OnPreviewMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs
>   e)
>      at System.Windows.UIElement.OnPreviewMouseDownThunk(Object sender,
>   MouseButtonEventArgs e)
>      at
>   System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate
>   genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
>      at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler,
>   Object target)
>      at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object
>   target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
>      at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source,
>   RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
>      at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender,
>   RoutedEventArgs args)
>      at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args,
>   Boolean trusted)
>      at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
>      at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs
>   input)
>      at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport
>   inputReport)
>      at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr
>   hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32
>   x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
>      at
>   System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr
>   hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
>      at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr
>   hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
>      at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr
>   wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
>      at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
>      at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
>      at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object
>   source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter,
>   Delegate catchHandler)

Comment: Perhaps somewhere you are trying to fire OnPropertyChanged without null checking it?

Comment: is it working in 32 bit but not 64bit windows 7?

Comment: Please provide a full stack trace (and it could also help you determine the root cause, BTW)

Comment: @SimonMourier Actually he did post the full stack trace, I edited most of it out since it was enormous and contained a lot of information I thought unnecessary, but if you think it should be in there, feel free to roll back my edit.

Comment: @OP - Did you get the solution for this? I am facing same problem.

Comment: could you provide the relevant XAML code? Seems interesting.